iOS/OSx: CSS Nesting With Host Selector Not Working
CSS Nesting With :host Not Working On iOS/OSx
While I already solved this issue for myself with a workaround, I bring this up for two reasons...

I would like to know if this is actually a bug or not
I searched everything under the sun and could not find anything relevant, other than the following SO Question...

"WebComponent nested CSS is invalid"
This may be a duplicate but, again, I am more interested to know if this issue is considered a bug so that I may report it to the proper party.
There is also more description & context provided below, for anyone who's interested.
Does NOT Work
:host {
    border: solid 10px tomato;
    
    .app.header {
        .header.title {
            background-color: tomato;
        }
    }
}

DOES Work
:host {
    border: solid 10px tomato;
}

.app.header {
    .header.title {
        background-color: tomato;
    }
}

Question
Should this be considered a bug on iOS/OSx? Why/not?
If so, should this be reported to Apple or the various browser manufacturers?
Context
This issue does not appear at all across virtually all browsers on both Windows and Android. However, both Safari and Chrome (and likely others) on iOS -- and MacOS, as far as I can tell -- behold the exact same behavior of the issue at hand.
This, to me, suggests that it is actually more of an Apple/OS level issue as opposed to one of the the browser manufacturers -- but I am not certain.
Please let me know a) if this is actually a bug and, b), what the right channel to report it through is. Otherwise, please inform me of what or why this is not actually a bug and perhaps what the better way to remedy this is.

As I already said in my answer you refer to: It is because of the shadowRoot, not a bug. If you want to dig deeper abuse the Web Components issue list at https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents where the Browser vendors hang out

My Own Workaround
I resolved the issue the exact same way for all browsers across iOS and MacOS with the following...
:host {
    border: solid 10px tomato;
}

.app.header {
    .header.title {
        background-color: tomato;
    }
}

The question remains, what is actually causing this?
